# updating with mongoose results in error path must be string

Tags: node.js, mongoose

got it working with .create, delete and find.
I'm having trouble finding out how to update something.

```
app.put('/api/flavours/:flavour_id', function(req, res){
flavours.where({_id : req.params.flavour_id })
.update({inventory : true},
    function(err, updateInventory){
    if(err) res.send(err);
     flavours.find(function(err, flavourscallback){
        if(err) res.send(err)
        res.json(flavourscallback);
    });
});
```

});

any help would be much appreciated.
I'm having trouble understanding the mongoose documentation :/

Comment: Before you call flavours.where(), do console.log(req.params.flavour_id), does it print a value?

Comment: yes yes. i deleted previous comment. 
console logging the id works. followed by put and the path including the id.
and then TypeError: path must be a string :/

Answer (score 0):

well, apparantly mongoose wants it different.
got it working like this:
    flavours.where('_id').equals(req.params.flavour_id)